# Find most recent measurement in one-to-many relationship?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm currently trying to return a single value from a related table in an Access 2007 query, which is connected to the main table in a one-to-many relationship. For formatting reasons, I would like to avoid using a subreport.

The use case is simple: the main report lists metrics; each metric can have many measurements. I would like to list only the most recent measurement in the table, based on the measurement date.

In the access query builder, I can happily add the measurements to the query; I have currently only worked out how to do this with two separate columns (one for the measurement value, and another for the measurement date). What I would like to do is get the list of measurement values, sorted by date, so that I can get the latest measurement for each metric; unfortunately the query builder doesn't let me do this, as it only gives me the option to sort by the column itself, not another column.

How can I get only the most recent measurement (accepting there will be some odd behaviour with duplicate dates, which I will handle with rules elsewhere), based on the date column, in the query builder?

The structure of my tables is:

```
DFS_Metric
-------------
ID
DFS_ID
Metric_ID

Metric
-------------
ID
Description
Unit

Metric_Value_Measurement
-------------
ID
Metric_ID
Measurement_Date
Measurement_Value
```

EDIT: Based on the comments below, I have written the following SQL, which seems to be giving me a syntax error - I would appreciate any assistance on where I'm going wrong:

```
SELECT Desired_Future_State_Metric.Desired_Future_State_ID
    ,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Metric_ID
    ,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Target_Value
    ,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Target_Date
    ,Metric.Description
    ,Metric.Unit
    ,Metric_Value_Measurement.Measurement_Date
FROM (
    (
        Metric INNER JOIN Desired_Future_State_Metric 
                ON Metric.ID = Desired_Future_State_Metric.Metric_ID
        ) INNER JOIN Metric_Unitvalue ON Metric.ID = Metric_Unitvalue.Metric_ID
    )
INNER JOIN Metric_Value_Measurement ON (
        Metric.ID = Metric_Value_Measurement.Metric_ID
        AND (
            SELECT Measurement_Date
            FROM Metric_Value_Measurement
            WHERE Metric_ID = Metric.ID
            ) = Metric_Value_Measurement.Measurement_Date
        )
GROUP BY Desired_Future_State_Metric.Desired_Future_State_ID
    ,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Metric_ID
    ,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Target_Value
    ,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Target_Date
    ,Metric.Description
    ,Metric.Unit
    ,Metric_Value_Measurement.Measurement_Date;
```

Comment: I never use the query builder. In SQL you would use a statement like SELECT m.*, mvm.* FROM metric m JOIN Metric_Value_Measurement mvm ON mvm.Metric_ID=m.ID AND mvm.Measurement_Date=(SELECT MAX(Measurement_Date) FROM Metric_Value_Measurement WHERE Metric_ID=m.ID). As you said, this can generate duplicate rows if there are more than one measurements with the same Metric_ID and Measurement_Value. You could try to write this SQL statement and then see how the query builder shows it to you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I've added some code above, which I feel is close, but I haven't quite got there yet.

Comment: What is the full syntax error message?

Comment: The full error message is simply "syntax error in query expression 'Metric.ID = Metric_Value_Measurement.Metric_ID AND (SELECT Measurement_Date FROM Metric_Value_Measurement WHERE Metric_ID = '1') = Metric_Value_Measurement.Measurement_Dat'. (not a typo - it misses the 'e' at the end, but it's in the code).

Comment: I've done a check to ensure that the expression 'SELECT Measurement_Date FROM Metric_Value_Measurement WHERE Metric_ID = 1' works in a separate query on its own, which it does. I have also confirmed that removing the "AND" section from the inner join causes no error messages, so the problem is that section.

Comment: I dont think you can have a full SELECT in your ON-clause. As far as SQL is concerned it could give back more than one dataset. What Frazz proposed was ... Date=(SELECT MAX()... which gives back THE ONE maximum value...

Answer (score 1):

Long nested SQL statements can be a real pain in access. I would make a query that groups by measurement_ID, and takes the most recent date and then link that query to the measurement table again:

```
QUERY 'MostRecentMeasurements':
SELECT Metric_ID, MAX(Measurement_date) as MostRecentMeasurementDate FROM Measurement
GROUP BY Metric_ID

QUERY2:
SELECT Metric_ID, Measurement_value FROM Measurement INNER JOIN MostRecentMeasurements ON
(Measurement.Metric_ID=MostRecentMeasurements.Metric_ID) AND (Measurement.Measurement_date = 
MostRecentMeasurements.MostRecentMeasurementDate)
```